# Android: Changing the theme of a dialog fragment

Tags: android

I have this code for a datepicker dialogfragment

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Use the current date as the default date in the picker
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

// Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
}

public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
// Do something with the date chosen by the user
}
}
```

And im running it like this:

```
DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
                newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
```

This is giving me this dialog:

[image]

When I want it to give me something like this:

[image]

How can I change the theme programmatically or through xml? I prefer xml so there's less code but I dont mind...

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Datepicker`constructor accepts a Theme as a parameter:

```
DatePickerDialog(Context context, int theme, this, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth);
```

So theme parameter is:

```
android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_NoActionBar
```

Edit: I think the one you're looking for is:

```
 public static final int Theme_Holo_Dialog_NoActionBar = 16973937;
```